# Automatically select an item from populated combobox with binding? Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, select, combobox

Lets say i have the following two controls.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Events}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Name"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEvent, Mode=TwoWay}"
         Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="5"/>
```

and

```
<ComboBox x:Name="VenueBox"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VenueNames}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedVenueName, Mode=TwoWay}"
          Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          Margin="10"/>
```

The ListBox is bound to an ObservableCollection which "holds" a custom class. The ComboBox is bound to an ObservableCollection of strings. Now the custom class has a string property which values are from the combobox. The thing i want is if i select an item in the ListBox, then automatically select that value from the ComboBox. Is it possible with pure XAML or some action in code behind is a must?  I hope my explanation is clear, thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you using MVVM at all?  This is a great example where a view model can do all this logic for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to read between the lines here.  You have a "Event" class which represents some event.  Events occur at some date and time and a location which we are calling a "Venue", the "Event" class has a string property which is the name of the venue.

You also have a list of possible venue names.

The object you are binding to has `SelectedEvent` property of type "Event" and a `SelectedVenue` property of type `string`.  The rule you wish to apply is that when a Event is chosen in the list box the `SelectedVenue` can only be the venue specified by the event.

So the real question is: *where does the enforcement of this rule belong?*

This is not really the job of the view to apply.   The model to which you are binding should be aware of this rule.  Code in the `SelectedEvent` property setter should ensure the correct value of `SelectedVenue` is applied.

The View will then simply reflect the current state of the model but it is the model's responsibility to understand what "correct" state is not the view's.

Comment: Thank you Anthony, i did that meanwhile what you wrote and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to bind the `SelectedItem` of the ComboBox differently *(having a dedicated property seems superfluous anyway since you already have `SelectedEvent`)* this should do it:

```xml
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedEvent.Venue, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

*(I don't know the actual name of the venue property so that might need to be adjusted to your model)*

Comment: Thank you, you gave me a good solution, if i don't need that "extra" property. I wish i could accept both yours and Anthonys answer.